# Toggle table and icon

Tags: jquery, html

I have a script which helps me to toggle my table but it fails for icon. So Please help me to modify it a bit. Here I am fetching the class name after click and finally I am performing toggle operation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function alok(obj){
var s= $(obj).attr('class');

$("."+s+":not(:first)").toggle(function() {
$('.'+s).children("img").attr("src","http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/ExpandSign.gif");
}, function() {
    $('.'+s).children("img").attr("src","http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/CollapseSign.gif");
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr  class="b" onclick=alok(this)><td><img src="http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/CollapseSign.gif">qw</td></tr>
<tr  class="b"><td>alok</td></tr>
<tr  class="b"><td>verma</td></tr>
<tr  class="c" onclick=alok(this)><td>qw</td></tr>
<tr  class="c"><td>alok</td></tr>
<tr  class="c"><td>verma</td></tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
function alok(obj){
   var s= $(obj).attr('class');
   var $img=$('.'+s).find("img");
   var src=($img.attr("src")=='http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/ExpandSign.gif') ?
        'http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/CollapseSign.gif':
        'http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/ExpandSign.gif';
   $img.attr("src",src);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'find' not 'children', 'children' just check one level down while find goes deeper

```
<script>
function alok(obj){
var s= $(obj).attr('class');

$("."+s+":not(:first)").toggle(function() {
$('.'+s).find("img").attr("src","http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/ExpandSign.gif");
}, function() {
        $('.'+s).find("img").attr("src","http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/CollapseSign.gif");
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

```
function alok(obj){
var s = $(obj).attr('class');

    if( !$(obj).hasClass('collapse') ){
        $(obj).children().children("img").attr("src","http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/ExpandSign.gif");
        $(obj).addClass('collapse');
    } else {
        $(obj).children().children("img").attr("src","http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/CollapseSign.gif");
        $(obj).removeClass('collapse');
    }

}
```